# Create diagram in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if is possible to create diagram from similar dataset, like data table below:

```
col0                       col1                        col2          col3
name                       <NA>                        <NA>          <NA>      
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    cat          vertebrates     
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    centipede    arthropods    
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    milipede     arthropods      
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    snail        mollusc      
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    fly          insect    
name   cat, centipede, milipede, snail, flay, worm    worm         invertebrates
```

and create diagram with R that would be more or less similar to picture below:

[image]

Comment: Try something like `foodweb` package.

Comment: `DiagrammeR`, `networkD3` and a few others of that sort can make such diagrams, but where is this hierarchy represented in that data snippet?

Comment: the data I'm working with have no hierarchy so R diagram should itself take value like "vertebrates" and "invertebrates" go down like picture below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try igraph starting with the following df:

```
library(igraph)   
df
   col0                                   col1          col2          col3
1  name                                   <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
2  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm   vertebrates        animal
3  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm invertebrates        animal
4  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm           cat   vertebrates
5  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm     centipede    arthropods
6  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm      milipede    arthropods
7  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm    arthropods invertebrates
8  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm       mollusc invertebrates
9  name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm         snail       mollusc
10 name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm        insect invertebrates
11 name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm           fly        insect
12 name cat,centipede,milipede,snail,flay,worm          worm invertebrates

df <- df[df$col1 != '<NA>',]
species <- union(df$col3, df$col2)
df <- df[c('col3', 'col2')]
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = species)
plot(g,vertex.size=2, vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="cyan", 
     edge.arrow.size=0.5, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g, root='animal'))
```

[image]